# How to Handle Date Client/Server

Tags: javascript, java, date

I'm creating a date:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
//calendar.setTimeInMillis(-9223372036854775808L);
//calendar.setTime(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
calendar.set(0, 0, 0);
return calendar;
```

After saving to database (HSQLDB in timespan mode)
The value is this:

```
0002-11-31 0:30 -> which i don't care about that much...
```

after sending it to client the value is as following:

```
{"id":42,"startDate":-62072796600000,"price":12.0,"position":{"id":43,"title":"lolo","wages":null,"personnel":null}}
```

in my model i create a datetime from it:

```
new Date(startDate)
```

and when i send back model to database:
it's like:

```
{"id":42,"startDate":"0002-12-28T20:30:00.000Z","price":12,"position":{"id":43,"title":"lolo","wages":[],"personnel":[]},"startDateActualValue":-62072796600000}
```

and it is o server:

```
0002-11-28 8:30
```

i also tried to sent actual recieved value, directly to server, it wasn't 3 day off but it still was off

any idea... also i be greatful if it does not affect my model:

This model is what i get from my service, and is what i send to server

```
class WageVm {
    public id: number;
    public startDate: Date;
    public price: number;
    public position: PositionVm;

    constructor(id: number, startDate: Date|string|number, price: number, position: PositionVm) {
        this.setup();
        if (id != undefined)this.id = id;
        if (startDate != undefined) {
            if (typeof startDate == "number") {
                this.startDate = new Date(<number>startDate);
            }else if(typeof startDate == "string"){
                this.startDate = new Date(<string>startDate);
            }else if (typeof startDate == "Date") {
                this.startDate = <Date>startDate;
            }else{
                throw new Error("Cannot Cast '"+ (typeof startDate).toString() + "' to 'Date'");
            }
        }
        if (price != undefined)this.price = price;
        if (position != undefined)this.position = position;
    }

    private setup() {
        this.id = 0;
        this.startDate = null;
        this.price = 0;
        this.position = null;
    }

    public getGregorianStartDate():string{
        return this.startDate.getFullYear().toString()
            +'-'+this.startDate.getMonth()
            +'-'+this.startDate.getDay();
    }

    //??? is used at all? :-/
    public isValidPersianDate():boolean{
        try{
            if(!moment(this.startDate).isValid())
                return false;
            //test on persian
            moment(this.startDate).format('jYYYY/jM/jD');
            return true;
        }catch (err){
            return false;
        }
    }

    public getPersianStartDate():string{
        try{
            return moment(this.startDate).format('jYYYY/jM/jD');
        }catch (err){
            return "";
        }
    }

    get persianStartDate(): string {
        return this.getPersianStartDate();
    }
}
```

### Update: Another test

This time i set (HARD CODE): "startDate":"0002-12-28T20:30:00.000Z" on client and change it to the date i send: "startDate":"0002-12-31T00:00:00.000Z" now:
[image]
as you can see it's fine, then i got same error that i generate through my code "Date should be same", so i look into the date variable, this time, time on one of them was: -62072784000000 and on other: -62072796600000

Comment: Can you check if the client and server have the same current time and date configured in the OS? Also check timezones and the way both client and server create a date.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker for now the server is my machine, so they both own same time, and same timezone, BTW i rather like to truncate time, but it's not possible...

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker any news?